# How to return the path from ExpandUNCFileName funtion of mapped drive?

Tags: delphi, windows-10

I am using Delphi 5. I originally had problems copying a file from a network mapped drive. If I use the UNC path I can copy the file.  The problem is I wont always know the UNC path.  I am using windows 10, 64 bit.  Is there a solution that would allow me to obtain the UNC path?  Every time I use the ExpandUNCFileName function it returns the path N:\tmp\file1.mdb instead of \hermes\apps\tmp\file1.mdb.  If I run the code on XP or Windows 7 it returns the UNC path correctly but when I run it on Windows 10 it fails and gives me the path with the drive letter.

What I am trying to do is run an install program which updates a database file.  For it to work I need to copy the database file locally.  Now the problem happens when I first start the update program exe, my windows 10 forces the program into run administrator.  As soon as I run the exe it pulls up an administrator login.  It only does this on  windows 10.  With windows 7, XP it does not ask or force it to run as administrator.

Please help if you can, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I can bypass windows from elevating my app to run as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExpandUNCFileName` works correctly. If you call that function from a context which has the drive letter mapped, then it will return the desired UNC name.

The problem therefore must be that when you call the function the drive is not mapped. Common reason for that would be that your code was executing in a service, or under a user account that does not map the drive, but there are other reasons.

Exactly how to solve your problem is not clear from here. You might solve it by making sure that the drive letter is always mapped. However, this is a potentially brittle approach, as you are discovering.

Perhaps a more reliable approach would be to operate exclusively with UNC names. This after all is the reason for their existence. So, when the user provides you a path to a network directory or file, convert it at that point to a UNC name. From that point on use that UNC name.

If you don't want your program to be elevated then you need to either give it an application manifest, or change its name. Executables without application manifests, and with names like update or patch, are elevated by UAC aware versions of Windows. UAC was introduced 12 years ago, it is perhaps time for you to get up to speed with the implications for developers. Not least because your old Delphi 5 development environment predates UAC, and therefore will not generate and link a manifest for you.

Comment: The Drive letter is mapped. The problem is I cannot use ExpandUNCFileName when windows 10 elevates the user to Admin.  For whatever reason when the user runs my app windows forces it to run as admin. I was told that you must run the app with the same user that created the drive mapping.  Is there a way I can bypass windows from elevating my app to run as admin?

Comment: Clearly the drive isn't mapped in the context that the code executes. That's what I said.

Comment: If I change the program name to Program1 it still wants to run as admin.  Not sure what you mean by Application manifest.

Comment: The fact remains that it the drive isn't mapped in the context of the code that executes it. Likely related to elevation. If your app doesn't need to elevate then it really shouldn't. I point the way for you to arrange that. Using UNC names is much less brittle. If you can use them, do so. You also need to understand UAC. Now a rather old technology. Read about it on MSDN. No shortcut here. It will take you time to learn about this. Don't expect to avoid that.

Comment: Application manifests are a well documented part of Windows development. On MSDN. It's not the place to reproduce that documentation. You will need to do some research here. You are clearly frustrated. But please don't take it out on those helping. I know you want a quick fix but there isn't one. You have to spend the time to learn and understand UAC.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to resolve my problem by  lowering the elevation to copy the file from the network. I had no idea why windows 10 was elevating my app and when I changed the name from UpdateArchive to UpdArchive I was able to control the elevation. Thanks again for your help.