# Is there a way to determine if a shared path and a mapped local path are the same?

Tags: delphi, filenames, filepath, file-handling

Let's say I have a file share at `\\cloud\MyShare` that is mapped to `J:\Mason` on my computer.  If I have two filenames, `\\cloud\MyShare\MyFolder\MyFile.dat` and `J:\Mason\MyFolder\MyFile.dat`, is there any RTL or WinAPI routine for my code to establish that these two are in fact referring to the same file?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410705/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c-sharp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891064/how-can-i-determine-that-several-file-paths-formats-point-to-the-same-physical-l?

Comment: You must at least **open** all files and then issue [`GetFileInformationByHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle) on them to then compare `BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION.dwVolumeSerialNumber`, `.nFileIndexHigh` and `.nFileIndexLow`. Do not open and close each file, as then values may differ.

Comment: One building block for shared drive to UNC is System.SysUtils.ExpandUNCFileName .  Check out SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593987 as well for a caveat about user context.

Comment: See Registry Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network Value RemotePath